# C# WPF AutoCompleteBox - similar named items returning first match in the list

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, autocomplete, selecteditem

I have a AutoCompleteBox which I search by using a ProductCode. The item source for the autocompletebox is a list `List<Product>` where Product has following properties: ProductCode,ProductID,ProductBrandCode.

It all works fine except when I try to retrieve SelectedItem property when selected product has the same ProductCode as another product in the list.

So for example, lets say I have 6 products:

```
 ProductID | ProductCode | ProductBrandCode 
 1              t1                abc
 2              t34               zyx
 3              test123           abc
 4              test123           zxc 
 5              test123           asd
 6              t23               asd
```

If I select the 5th product (ID of 5), the SelectedItem returns the product with ID = 3. Same thing happens if I select product with the id=4, I always get the first product that matches the ProductCode. I'm assuming that this is caused by the fact that my ValueMemberPath is set to ProductCode witch in this case is not unique and the autoCompleteBox somehow picks up the first matching ProductCode. It works perfectly fine if I select a product that doesn't have a duplicate ProductCode in the list.

This is how it looks in xaml:

```
 <my:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="autoTxtBoxProductCode"
                 verticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Height="25" Margin="116,10,0,0"
                 Width="144" Background="#FFEDF4AB" 
                 TabIndex="2001" IsTabStop="True"
                 Populating="AutoBoxPopulateProductCode"    
                 ValueMemberPath="ProductCode"
                 Style="{StaticResource autoTextBoxInError}"
                 Validation.Error="Validation_Error"
                 PreviewKeyUp="autoTxtBoxProductCode_PreviewKeyUp"
                 IsTextCompletionEnabled="False" MinimumPrefixLength="2"
                 Text="{Binding Path=ProductCode,
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                        ValidatesOnDataErrors=true,
                        NotifyOnValidationError=true,
                        Mode=TwoWay}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ProductID}">
                        <my:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductBrandCode}"
                                               FontWeight="Bold"
                                               Foreground="Black"
                                               Width="65" FontSize="14"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductCode}"
                                                  Foreground="Black"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </my:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </my:AutoCompleteBox>
```

And in my Code I retrieve the selected item like this:

```
 private void autoTxtBoxProductCode_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
   Product prd = (Product)(autoTxtBoxProductCode.SelectedItem);
   MessageBox.Show(prd.ProductID.ToString());
  }
```

Is there any way around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The problem is when the DropDown is closing the box updates the selected item again. So I suppress this event in my own AutoCompleteBox.

```
class CustomAutoCompleteBox : System.Windows.Controls.AutoCompleteBox
{
    private bool dropDown = false;

    protected override void OnDropDownOpening(System.Windows.Controls.RoutedPropertyChangingEventArgs<bool> e)
    {
        base.OnDropDownOpening(e);
        dropDown = false;
    }

    protected override void OnDropDownClosing(System.Windows.Controls.RoutedPropertyChangingEventArgs<bool> e)
    {
        base.OnDropDownClosing(e);
        dropDown = true;
    }

    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!dropDown)
            base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
        else
            dropDown = false;
    }
}
```

I hope I could help you.

---

Edit: I forgot the OnDropDownOpening Event to reset.